# SAS Operand Error

Tags: sas

I am getting an error when trying to run the following code:

```
%MACRO CreateReports;

%DO I=1 %TO &LBRNUM; 

%let lbr = &&VAR&I;
%let lbrTxt = %sysfunc(putn(&LBR,z9.));
%let now = %sysfunc(date(),DATE9.);
%let mnth= %sysfunc(intnx(month, "&now"d, -1, e), yymmn6.);
%let dataAsOf = %sysfunc(intnx(month, "&now"d, -1, e), mmddyy10.);
%let fname = %sysfunc(cat(&path,&lbrTxt._TTL_Backup_&mnth,.xlsx));

%put &lbrTxt &mnth &fname;
```

The error reads: 
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric
       operand is required. The condition was: &LBRNUM

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Well, what does LBRNULM resolve into? We can't see the value. Run your macro with `option mprint symbolgen` to see if there's any extra information in the log. And post your exact log and full code, that's clearly a snippet.

Comment: Also, which line is causing the error? On an unrelated note, you can use the automatic macro variable `&sysdate9` in place of the `now` variable.

Comment: `%put lbrnum;` would be helpful also.

Comment: It looks like LBRNUM isn't set at all - it doesn't resolve, leaving '&LBRNUM' in the code, which is why the error message says that the condition was '&LBRNUM'. You need to set LBRNUM to the number of iterations you want the loop to run, and you also need macro variables VAR1, VAR2, VAR3 etc to be set as well, before you run this code.